# Discrepancy in Flow Velocity between Y and T Junctions in PVC Pipe System

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I am currently working on a project involving a PVC pipe system for drainage, where I use a 3" main pipe with 25 secondary 1" drain pipes feeding into it. In my simulation, I have considered two options for connecting the secondary drain pipes to the main pipe: a 3"/1" **T-junction** and a 3"/1" **Y-junction**.

Initially, I anticipated that the Y-junction, due to its streamlined flow along the direction of the 3" main pipe, would result in a stronger water flow compared to the T-junction. However, my simulation results have shown an unexpected outcome – the system using the Y-junction exhibits an outlet water velocity only half as much as the T-junction.

I have meticulously triple-checked all boundary conditions for both scenarios, and they appear to be identical. Despite this, the significant difference in water velocity persists, leaving me puzzled as to the underlying cause.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions regarding the possible reasons behind this observed variation in flow velocities between the Y and T junction configurations. Additionally, if anyone has encountered a similar issue or has expertise in fluid dynamics, your guidance would be immensely valuable.

Thank you for your time and assistance.
[image: Model in 2 cases]